# How to filter an object by its values in ES6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, filtering

What is the best way to filter an object this way in ES6?

Starting data:

```
const acceptedValues = ["value1", "value3"]
const myObject = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop2: "value2",
    prop3: "value3"
}
```

Expected output:

```
filteredObject = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop3: "value3"
}
```

Comment: Best way in terms of what? A simple loop over the object's properties would do.

Comment: If possible, try to capture accepted keys instead of values to make this easy.

Comment: In term of efficiency mostly. A simple loop would do the trick indeed, But ES6 and "modern" array methods could make it easier. The answer with .reduce() is a nice example of that imo.

Comment: Best way? Don't use an `Object` (but an `Array`) from the beginning.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to create new object and `includes()` to check if value of object exists in array.

```js
const acceptedValues = ["value1", "value3"]
const myObject = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: "value2",
  prop3: "value3"
}

var filteredObject = Object.keys(myObject).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (acceptedValues.includes(myObject[e])) r[e] = myObject[e]
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(filteredObject)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why using `.filter` doesn't work in this case when I have an object? `this.activeUsers = window.users.filter( function(user) {// return ( (user.test === '0') && (user.isok === '0') ); return user.user_id === 1; });` getting the error `.filter is not a function`

Comment: @W.Doch because filter does not apply to objects, only arrays

Answer (score 11):

For ES6 and if

- your task can be solved with only filtering based on keys and
- you need static code (you know exactly, what properties you need to filter) and
- it does not depend on the app state,

than you can use the following destructuring technique:

```
const myObject = {
  prop1: 'value1',
  prop2: 'value2',
  prop3: 'value3'
}
const { prop2, ...filteredObject } = myObject

console.info({ filteredObject, prop2 })
```

And you will have:

```
filteredObject: {prop1: "value1", prop3: "value3"}
prop2: "value2"
```

Comment: This is filtering based on the *key not matching*, whereas the question seeks to filter on the *value matching*.

Answer (score 6):

Just to build on top of @Nenad Vracar good answer you could use an object instead of the Array with `includes` for faster lookup:

```js
const acceptedValues = ["value1", "value3"];
const myObject = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: "value2",
  prop3: "value3"
};

const lookup = acceptedValues.reduce( (memo, prop) => {
  memo[prop] = true;
  return memo;
});

const filteredObject = Object.keys(myObject).reduce((filtered, key) => {
  if(lookup[myObject[key]]){
    filtered[key] = myObject[key];
  }
  return filtered;
}, {});

console.log(filteredObject);
```

Nor that the `includes` doesn't do the job, but I thought to provide an alternative view.

Answer (score 6):

Since I haven't seen an answer using `Object.entries` here's one. Note, due to `Object.entries()` implementation being significantly slower than `Object.keys()`, this will also be slower than the accepted answer, but some may prefer this for readability or extendability (easier to pass a different filtering function).

```
const acceptedValues = ["value1", "value3"];
const myObject = {
    prop1:"value1",
    prop2:"value2",
    prop3:"value3"
};
const filteredEntries = Object.entries(myObject).filter(([, v]) => acceptedValues.includes(v));
const filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(filteredEntries);
```

Or as a longish one-liner:

```
const filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myObject).filter(([, v]) => accepted.includes(v)));
```

Comment: That's the one I was looking for! I knew Object.entries would be the way to go. Good to note it's slower (but that is rarely an issue for most use cases)

Comment: TypeError, Object.fromEntries is not a function

Comment: What browser are you using? Should be supported on all modern browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks for the `fromEntries` suggestion. It's nice.

Answer (score 5):

Why not a simple for loop?

```js
const acceptedValues = ["value1","value3"]
const myObject = {
    prop1:"value1",
    prop2:"value2",
    prop3:"value3"
};
var  filteredObject = {};
for(e in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
      if (acceptedValues.indexOf(myObject[e]) != -1) {
          filteredObject[e] = myObject[e];
      }
    }
}
console.log(filteredObject);
```

Comment: At least then use a generator haha

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple for loop and get object by key.

```js
const acceptedValues = ["value1","value3"]
const myObject = {
    prop1:"value1",
    prop2:"value2",
    prop3:"value3"
}

Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function( value ) {
    for( var prop in this ) {
        if( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
             if( this[ prop ] === value )
                 return prop;
        }
    }
}

for (var i in acceptedValues) {
  if (myObject.getKeyByValue(acceptedValues[i])){
    console.log(acceptedValues[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Changing a prototype is generally not recommended for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter(myObject){
  var obj=Object.assign({},myObject);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      if(acceptedValues.indexOf(obj[key])<0) delete obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
}
const filteredObject=filter(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the "best way" is the Lodash way

```
const filtered = _.pick(myObject, acceptedValues)
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick

Comment: just watched one of your vids .. fireship is awesome!

Comment: this filters by keys, so not what the question asked for

Answer (score 0):

```
const newObj = {};
for(let key of Object.keys(myObject)){
  if(acceptedValues.includes(key)){
    newObj[key] = myObject[key]
  }
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.