# JavaScript: How to filter data in an array

Tags: javascript

I have following object in JS:

```
[
  {
    "financial_year":1,
    "mainline_revenue":18743.0,
    "regional_revenue":2914.0,
    "other_revenue":3198.0,
    "non_operating_items":-1983.0
  },
  {
    "financial_year":2,
    "mainline_revenue":20218.0,
    "regional_revenue":3131.0,
    "other_revenue":3394.0,
    "non_operating_items":-3233.0
  },
  {
    "financial_year":3,
    "mainline_revenue":30802.0,
    "regional_revenue":6322.0,
    "other_revenue":5526.0,
    "non_operating_items":-1367.0
  }
]
```

**financial_year** is the unique identifier which I want to use to filter data. How can I filter data where for example financial_year is 2 and put the other values in an array?

Comment: google: MDN array methods. You need filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter an object with its values in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025984/how-to-filter-an-object-with-its-values-in-es6)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: This is an array of objects. Not a dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on arrays. `filter` takes a callback which returns true or false (more accurately, a truthy or falsey value). If it returns true, that object is included in the resulting array.

```js
let input = [
  {
    "financial_year":1,
    "mainline_revenue":18743.0,
    "regional_revenue":2914.0,
    "other_revenue":3198.0,
    "non_operating_items":-1983.0
  },
  {
    "financial_year":2,
    "mainline_revenue":20218.0,
    "regional_revenue":3131.0,
    "other_revenue":3394.0,
    "non_operating_items":-3233.0
  },
  {
    "financial_year":3,
    "mainline_revenue":30802.0,
    "regional_revenue":6322.0,
    "other_revenue":5526.0,
    "non_operating_items":-1367.0
  }
];
let output = input.filter((obj) => obj.financial_year !== 2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

Or rewritten with ES5:

```js
var input = [
  {
    "financial_year":1,
    "mainline_revenue":18743.0,
    "regional_revenue":2914.0,
    "other_revenue":3198.0,
    "non_operating_items":-1983.0
  },
  {
    "financial_year":2,
    "mainline_revenue":20218.0,
    "regional_revenue":3131.0,
    "other_revenue":3394.0,
    "non_operating_items":-3233.0
  },
  {
    "financial_year":3,
    "mainline_revenue":30802.0,
    "regional_revenue":6322.0,
    "other_revenue":5526.0,
    "non_operating_items":-1367.0
  }
];
var output = input.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.financial_year !== 2;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```