# How to filter json with key which have '0' as value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON response with the key and the value, I want to filter only those whose weight is **1** Any help is greatly appreciated

```
{
"post": 1,
"bio": 1,
"hashtag": 0,
"profile": 0,
}
```

expected output

```
{
"post": 1,
"bio": 1
}
```

Comment: Parse the JSON to a JavaScript object (`JSON.parse`), convert the object to an array (`Object.entries`), filter the array (`Array.prototype.filter`), convert the array to an object (`Object.fromEntries`) and serialize the object (`JSON.stringify`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an object with its values in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025984/how-to-filter-an-object-with-its-values-in-es6)

Comment: someone close this Q ...

Answer (score -2):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
const o = {
  "post": 1,
  "bio": 1,
  "hashtag": 0,
  "profile": 0,
};
let res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(([k,v])=>v===1));
console.log(res);
```